# How can I publish obfuscated with ProGuard jar using sbt?

Tags: sbt, proguard, sbt-proguard

I'm trying to publish obfuscated by ProGuard jar using sbt. I have this code so far, but it is not pushing obfuscated jar into the local ivy2 repo with `sbt publish-local`:

```
artifact in (Proguard, ProguardKeys.proguard) ~= {
  art => art.copy(`classifier` = Some("proguard"))
}
addArtifact(Artifact("myJar", "jar", "jar"), assembly in ProguardKeys.proguard)
publishArtifact in ProguardKeys.proguard := true
```

Did you do such things before or have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: "not doing the trick" isn't the best problem description you can give... Try adding more info if you want help

Comment: @JSantos thank you, updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick:

```
// do not publish source, javadoc and default jar
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false

// add the Proguard jar for publishing
addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, ProguardKeys.proguard), (ProguardKeys.proguard in Proguard) map { xs => xs.head })
```

With this config I disable publishing of the sources, javadoc and default jar, and add the jar generated by Proguard to be published. Now `publish[Local]` tasks publish only the pom and the Proguard jar.

Comment: What if I want to publish both the proguard .jar and the regular jar?

Comment: Then remove `publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false` from above.